# How to embed video in website with html/php, so it can't be downloaded by visitor?

Tags: php, html, video, html5-video

How can I embed a video in a website with html/php, so it can't be downloaded by a visitor? The visitor can just view the video but can't download it.

Comment: i think you must create your own Flash player like [KVS](http://www.kernel-video-sharing.com/en/) .

Comment: creating my own flash player? is there any premium code to be buyed?

Comment: i suggest this way because you can hide your encryption key or other codes in your .swf flash player (KVS) has this service.

Comment: should the video in swf format to?
If I have .mp4 video format, can I still use KVS?

Comment: yes your video is in mp4 format, flash player send some data to your server & get link, then plays the video. note that the KVS is sample system, you can search for more players.

Comment: oh ok, thanks for your answer. but is there some simpler? like puting some php code or js plugin?

Comment: i think you should implement your encryption system. i don't know other way. you can see [Video-Js](http://www.videojs.com/) player & it's plugins for getting help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are trying to stop someone 'stealing' the video then at the end of the day you can't - if the video plays on the users browser then it has to pass from the server to the users machine and a malicious user can capture it one way or another.

If you mean that you just want to default action to be that the video plays back rather than downloads, then using the standard HTML5  tag in the default way will provide this behaviour.

Assuming it is the 'stealing' case you are worried about then DRM is the technology most often used to address this concern - this encrypts the video so that someone copying it will not be able to play it back without the correct key. How you manage the keys is obviously critical but most of the common DRM providers will have established ways to securely manage the keys. The technology is quite complex so using a hosted video service which supports DRM might be an approach to consider (e.g. https://support.brightcove.com/en/video-cloud/docs/content-protection-drm or http://corp.kaltura.com/Products/Features/DRM).

Comment: oke, thanks for your comment. but are there some simpler way?

Comment: I guess it depends how you define simple! Have a look at the example here to see an example of how the standard HTML5 approach works (EME): http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/eme/basics/. Writing player using this yourself will be tricky so using an existing player like video.js is probably more realistic. You will still need to encrypt the video on the server side and handle key requests server side etc, and if you are looking for the simplest as opposed to the cheapest way to do this then one of the hosted services (example in the answer) is probably easiest.

Answer (score 0):

In your situation, right-click protection can make sense. This feature protects your video from unwanted downloads and works on any website. It blocks downloading on right mouse click and restricts accessing the file’s original source code. Optionaly, you can add a text or link to be shown on right mouse click that directs people to your website when they try to download your video. Learn more [here](https://www.cincopa.com/blog/protect-your-media-content-from-copyright-violation-with-cincopas-web-galleries/#utm_source=Stackoverflow&utm_campaign=iev0117&utm_medium=answers)